# Align column where each cell has two decimals with siunitx

Tags: tables, align, siunitx

I also want to align the second column.
The problem is, that there can't be two numbers in one cell
Is there a way to align the second column via digits even if there are more decimals?
I also used the input-ignore option to ignore the commas

```
\usepackage{tabular}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  l
  @{}}
{Radius} & {Luminosity}\\
0.30 &     [-195.728, 213.571] \\
0.000 &  [-2465.825, -1234.722] \\
0.648 &       [-35.587, 22.432] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can split into two columns and inject the brackets:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\NewDocumentCommand{\lbr}{}{[\thinspace}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rbr}{}{]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.3]
  >{\lbr}S[table-format=-4.3,table-space-text-pre=\lbr]
  @{, }
  S[table-format=-4.3,table-space-text-post=\rbr]<{\rbr}
}
\toprule
{Radius} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Luminosity}\\
\midrule
0.30  &  -195.728 &   213.571 \\
0.000 & -2465.825 & -1234.722 \\
0.648 &   -35.587 &    22.432 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A small final note: `\NewDocumentCommand` is provided by `xparse`, which is loaded by `siunitx`. Using it, `\lbr` becomes a “protected” command, so it can be used as a “text-pre” in an `S` column.

Comment: I rejected the edit adding `xparse` to the list of loaded packages on the grounds that I verified that the example compiles without it since `siunitx` already loads `xparse`. There might be merit in mentioning that `\NewDocumentCommand` is a `xparse` command and that `siunitx` loads `xparse`, but this should probably happen in a comment and not in an uncommented edit.

Comment: @moewe Thanks; I added a final comment with a short explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Split it into two columns:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
  S[table-format=1.3]
    @{\space[\thinspace}
  S[table-format=-4.3]
    @{,\space}
    S[table-format=-4.3]
        @{\thinspace]}
        @{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Radius} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Luminosity}\\
0.30 &     -195.728 & 213.571 \\
0.000 &  -2465.825 & -1234.722 \\
0.648 &       -35.587 & 22.432 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Rather than `\space[\thinspace`, use `\hspace{2\tabcolsep}[\thinspace` so as to restore the standard intercolumn spacing.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your suggestion, but this would misalign the header

Comment: Yes, you need to add the same material in `\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{\hspace*{2\tabcolsep}\phantom[\thinspace}{Radius}`. Possibly better is to inject the material with `>{[\thinspace}`

Comment: @egreg `File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.`

Comment: @egreg `>{[\thinspace}` will mess with siunitx alignment

Answer (score 1):

A variant layout:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
  S[table-format=1.3]
     >{[\,}S[table-format=-4.3, table-space-text-pre = {[}, table-align-text-pre=false]<{{,}}
@{\enspace}
    S[table-format=-4.3, table-space-text-post ={]}]
         <{$\!$]}
        @{}}
{Radius} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Luminosity}\\
0.30 & -195.728 & 213.571 \\
0.000 & -2465.825 & -1234.722 \\
0.648 & -35.587 & 22.432 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]