# Overview of Rasch model parameters in table - neat and compact

Tags: tables, formatting

Once again, I would be very happy about your help concerning the formatting of my table.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}  % Zeilenabstand im Text
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}     
\usepackage{tabularx,pdflscape,siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Itemparameter und Ergebnisse des Wald-Tests} 
    \label{tab:ergebnisse} 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
    %{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    %\scalebox{0.65}{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{7}{S[table-format=3.2]}} 

        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Itemschwierigkeit}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wald-Test{$^\ast$}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wald-Test{$^{\ast\ast}$}}  \\ \cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
        Items & {$\eta$} & {SE} & {KI} &{$z$}& {$p$}&{$z$}& {$p$}\\ \midrule
        Während der letzten Woche \ldots &&&&&&&\\[0.2cm]

    1. haben mich Dinge beunruhigt, die mir sonst nichts ausmachen
  &{0.02} & {0.13} & {-0.25; 0.28} &{-0.38}&   {0.70}&{-1.45}&{0.15}\\
    2. hatte ich kaum Appetit & {0.50} & {0.14}&{0.23 ; 0.78}& {2.91}& {0.004}&{1.91}&{0.06}\\      
    3. konnte ich meine trübsinnige Laune nicht loswerden, obwohl mich meine Freunde/ Familie versuchten, aufzumuntern & {0.83} & {0.15} &{0.55 ; 1.12}&{-1.31}&{0.19} &{-1.01}&{0.31}\\
    4. kam ich mir genauso gut vor wie andere [R] & {-1.64} & {0.15} &{-1.94 ; -1.35} &{1.35}& {0.18}&{-2.78}&{0.01}\\
    5. hatte ich Mühe, mich zu konzentrieren&  {-1.36}& {0.14} & {-1.64 ; -1.08}&{1.98}& {0.05}&{2.54}&{0.01}\\
    6. war ich deprimiert/niedergeschlagen& {-0.16}& {0.13}  & {-0.42 ;  0.10} &{-3.45}&{0.001}&{-0.41}&{0.68}\\ 
    7. war alles anstrengend für mich & {-0.62}& {0.13} &{-0.89 ; -0.36} &{-0.62}&{0.54}&{0.27}&{0.79}\\        
    8. dachte ich voller Hoffnung an die Zukunft [R] & { -2.50}& {0.18} & {-2.86 ; -2.14}& {3.06}& {0.002}&{0.44}&{0.66}\\  
    9. dachte ich, mein Leben ist ein einziger Fehlschlag & {2.08}  &{ 0.19}  & {1.70  ;  2.45}&{-0.92}&{0.36} &{0.39}&{0.69}\\
    10. hatte ich Angst &{0.44} & { 0.14} & {0.17 ; 0.71} &{-1.23}&{0.22}&{0.44}&{0.79}\\
    11. habe ich schlecht geschlafen & {-0.77} & {0.14} & {-1.04 ; -0.51}&{3.94}& {< 0.001}&{-0.07}&{0.95} \\
    12. war ich fröhlich gestimmt [R] & {-1.21}&{0.14} &{-1.49 ; -0.94} &{-1.29}&{0.20}& {-0.53}&{0.60}\\
    13. habe ich weniger als sonst geredet &{ 0.25} & {0.14} & {-0.02 ; 0.51}&{-0.35}&{0.73}&{2.82} &{0.01}\\
    14. fühlte ich mich einsam &{0.55}& {0.14} & {0.27  ;  0.82} &{-1.62}&{0.11}&{0.34}&{0.73}\\
    15. waren die Leute unfreundlich zu mir&{1.16}&{0.15}& {0.86 ; 1.45}&{3.20}&{0.001}&{0.93}&{0.35}\\         
    16. habe ich das Leben genossen [R] & {-0.96} &{ 0.14} & {-1.23 ; -0.70}&{-0.98}&{0.33}&{0.78}&{0.43}\\
    17. mußte ich weinen & {-1.61}&  {0.17} &{1.29 ; 1.94}&{-0.09}&{0.93}&{-1.75}&{0.08}\\
    18. war ich traurig &{ 0.42} &{0.14} & {0.16 ; 0.69}&{-3.01}&{0.003}&{-0.37}&{0.71}\\
    19. hatte ich das Gefühl, daß mich die Leute nicht leiden können & {1.21} & {0.15} & {0.91 ; 1.51} &{-0.09}&{0.93}&{-1.25}&{0.21}\\
    20. konnte ich mich zu nichts aufraffen &{ 0.17} & {0.14} & {-0.09 ;  0.44} &{0.26}&{0.79}&{1.53}&{0.13}\\
        \midrule 
\tiny $^\ast$  Median als Teilungskriterium;
\newline$^{\ast\ast}$ Geschlecht als Teilungskriterium


\end{tabularx}  
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Right now, my table looks something like this: 
[image: Table]

However, I am not really happy with my table, especially when it comes to the "KI" column. The numbers are all over the place. 
Does anyone pf you have any suggestions what I can try to make it look more symmetrical. Also, I don't know how I can align the negative numbers with the others. The columns where it says Wald test and underneath "p" and "z" do not appear to be symmetrical since the columns do not look to be exactly the same width to me.

Does anyone have any recommendations what I can do to make it look more symmetrical and nice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You've posted several questions on this site and have received several answer. However, you do not seem to have "accepted" (by clicking on the checkmark symbol) any of the answers. Please consider going over your previous queries and, if any answers strike you as particularly useful, accepting them.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions and observations, in no particular order:

- Don't encase the numbers in the data columns in curly braces, as doing so defeats the formatting actions of the `S` column type.
- Typeset the confidence interval numbers, well, as a confidence interval,
- Use hanging indentation in the first column
- Don't abuse `$^{\ast}$` and `$^{\ast\ast}$` to typeset footnote markers. Instead, use the `\tnote` macro and `tablenotes` environment provided by the `threeparttable` package.
- No need to use `\footnotesize` in the main table; use `\small` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % utf8, not 'latin9'
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} % Zeilenabstand im Text
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}     
\usepackage{tabularx,pdflscape,siunitx,booktabs}

% additional preamble instructions:
\usepackage{ragged2e,rotating}
%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487359/5001:
   \NewDocumentCommand{\lbr}{}{[}
   \NewDocumentCommand{\rbr}{}{\,]}
\usepackage[flushleft,para]{threeparttable}
\newlength\mylen  
\settowidth\mylen{3. }
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter1\hangindent\mylen}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\small %\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Itemparameter und Ergebnisse der Wald-Tests} 
\label{tab:ergebnisse} 
    %%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt} % default: 6pt
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2} % set default format
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{} 
              L 
              S
              S[table-format=1.2]
              >{\lbr}S[table-space-text-pre=\lbr]
              @{,\,} % comma rather than whitespace as column separator
              S[table-space-text-post=\rbr]<{\rbr}
              S
              S[table-space-text-pre={<\,}, table-format=1.3]
              S
              S[table-format=1.2] @{}} 

    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Itemschwierigkeit}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wald-Test\tnote{$*$}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Wald-Test\tnote{$**$}}  \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
    Items & {$\eta$} & {SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{KI} &{$z$}& {$p$} &{$z$}& {$p$}\\ 
    \midrule
    Während der letzten Woche \ldots && \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\            
    \addlinespace
    1. haben mich Dinge beunruhigt, die mir sonst nichts ausmachen &0.02 & 0.13 & -0.25 & 0.28 &-0.38&   0.70&-1.45&0.15\\
    2. hatte ich kaum Appetit & 0.50 & 0.14&0.23 & 0.78& 2.91& 0.004&1.91&0.06\\      
    3. konnte ich meine trübsinnige Laune nicht loswerden, obwohl mich meine Freunde\slash Familie versuchten, aufzumuntern & 0.83 & 0.15 &0.55 & 1.12&-1.31&0.19 &-1.01&0.31\\
    4. kam ich mir genauso gut vor wie andere [R] & -1.64 & 0.15 &-1.94 & -1.35 &1.35& 0.18&-2.78&0.01\\
    5. hatte ich Mühe, mich zu konzentrieren&  -1.36& 0.14 & -1.64 & -1.08&1.98& 0.05&2.54&0.01\\
    6. war ich deprimiert\slash niedergeschlagen& -0.16& 0.13  & -0.42 &  0.10 &-3.45&0.001&-0.41&0.68\\ 
    7. war alles anstrengend für mich & -0.62& 0.13 &-0.89 & -0.36 &-0.62&0.54&0.27&0.79\\        
    8. dachte ich voller Hoffnung an die Zukunft [R] &  -2.50& 0.18 & -2.86 & -2.14& 3.06& 0.002&0.44&0.66\\  
    9. dachte ich, mein Leben ist ein einziger Fehlschlag & 2.08  & 0.19  & 1.70  &  2.45&-0.92&0.36 &0.39&0.69\\
    10. hatte ich Angst &0.44 &  0.14 & 0.17 & 0.71 &-1.23&0.22&0.44&0.79\\
    11. habe ich schlecht geschlafen & -0.77 & 0.14 & -1.04 & -0.51&3.94& {<\,}0.001&-0.07&0.95 \\ 
    12. war ich fröhlich gestimmt [R] & -1.21&0.14 &-1.49 & -0.94 &-1.29&0.20& -0.53&0.60\\
    13. habe ich weniger als sonst geredet & 0.25 & 0.14 & -0.02 & 0.51&-0.35&0.73&2.82 &0.01\\
    14. fühlte ich mich einsam &0.55& 0.14 & 0.27  &  0.82 &-1.62&0.11&0.34&0.73\\
    15. waren die Leute unfreundlich zu mir&1.16&0.15& 0.86 & 1.45&3.20&0.001&0.93&0.35\\         
    16. habe ich das Leben genossen [R] & -0.96 & 0.14 & -1.23 & -0.70&-0.98&0.33&0.78&0.43\\
    17. mußte ich weinen & -1.61&  0.17 &1.29 & 1.94&-0.09&0.93&-1.75&0.08\\
    18. war ich traurig & 0.42 &0.14 & 0.16 & 0.69&-3.01&0.003&-0.37&0.71\\
    19. hatte ich das Gefühl, daß mich die Leute nicht leiden können & 1.21 & 0.15 & 0.91 & 1.51 &-0.09&0.93&-1.25&0.21\\
    20. konnte ich mich zu nichts aufraffen & 0.17 & 0.14 & -0.09 &  0.44 &0.26&0.79&1.53&0.13\\
    \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 

\smallskip\scriptsize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[$*$] Median als Teilungskriterium; 
\item[$**$] Geschlecht als Teilungskriterium.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- your table can be fit in `portrait` page orientation (actually you prescribe table width with `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{7}{S[table-format=3.2]}}` so)
- in MWE below are removed all curly braces around numbers as suggested in @Mico comments
- added is automatic numbering of rows
- redefined are `S` columns
- inserted is small additional vertical spaces in cells (using features of the `makecell` package)
- for text spacing is used the `setspace` package

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, pagesize, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}  % new
\onehalfspacing% Zeilenabstand im Text
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % new
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            makecell,  % new
            tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\newcounter{rownum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% not used

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \caption{Itemparameter und Ergebnisse des Wald-Tests}
    \label{tab:ergebnisse}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\stepcounter{rownum}\therownum.}r
                                 L  S[table-format=-1.2]
                                    S[table-format= 1.2]
                                >{[}S[table-format=-1.2,
                                      table-space-text-pre={]},
                                      table-space-text-post={]},
                                      table-align-text-pre=false]<{;}@{$\;$}
                                    S[table-format=-1.2]<{]}
                                    S[table-format=-1.2]
                                    S[table-format=1.3,
                                      table-comparator,
                                      table-space-text-pre=<]
                                    S[table-format=-1.2]
                                    S[table-format= 1.2]
                                 @{}}

    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Itemschwierigkeit}  
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wald-Test{$^\ast$}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wald-Test{$^{\ast\ast}$}}  \\ 
    \cmidrule{3-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8} \cmidrule(l){9-10}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Items}
    & {$\eta$} & {SE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{KI} 
                            & {$z$} & {$p$} & {$z$} & {$p$}\\ \midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{Während der letzten Woche  \dots }   \\[0.2cm]

& haben mich Dinge beunruhigt, die mir sonst nichts ausmachen
    &  0.02 & 0.13 & -0.25 & 0.28 & -0.38 & 0.70  & -1.45 & 0.15 \\
& hatte ich kaum Appetit 
    &  0.50 & 0.14 &  0.23 & 0.78 &  2.91 & 0.004 &  1.91 & 0.06 \\
& konnte ich meine trübsinnige Laune nicht loswerden, obwohl mich meine Freunde/Familie versuchten, aufzumuntern
    &  0.83 & 0.15 &  0.55 &  1.12 & -1.31 & 0.19  & -1.01 & 0.31 \\
& kam ich mir genauso gut vor wie andere [R] 
    & -1.64 & 0.15 & -1.94 & -1.35 & 1.35 & 0.18  & -2.78 & 0.01 \\
& hatte ich Mühe, mich zu konzentrieren
    & -1.36 & 0.14 & -1.64 & -1.08 &  1.98 & 0.05  &  2.54 & 0.01 \\
& war ich deprimiert/nieder\-geschlagen
    & -0.16 & 0.13 & -0.42 &  0.10 & -3.45 & 0.001 & -0.41 & 0.68 \\
& war alles anstrengend für mich 
    & -0.62 & 0.13 & -0.89 & -0.36 & -0.62 & 0.54  &  0.27 & 0.79 \\
& dachte ich voller Hoffnung an die Zukunft [R] 
    & -2.50 & 0.18 & -2.86 & -2.14 &  3.06 & 0.002 &  0.44 & 0.66 \\
& dachte ich, mein Leben ist ein einziger Fehlschlag 
    &  2.08 & 0.19 &  1.70 &  2.45 & -0.92 &  0.36 & 0.39 & 0.69 \\
& hatte ich Angst 
    &  0.44 &  0.14 & 0.17 &  0.71 &-1.23&0.22&0.44&0.79\\
& habe ich schlecht geschlafen 
    & -0.77 & 0.14 & -1.04 & -0.51 & 3.94 & <0.001 & -0.07 & 0.95 \\
& war ich fröhlich gestimmt [R] 
    & -1.21 & 0.14 & -1.49 & -0.94 & -1.29 & 0.20 & -0.53 & 0.60\\
& habe ich weniger als sonst geredet 
    &  0.25 & 0.14 & -0.02 &  0.51 & -0.35 & 0.73 &  2.82 & 0.01\\
& fühlte ich mich einsam 
    &  0.55 & 0.14 & 0.27 &  0.82 & -1.62 & 0.11 & 0.34 & 0.73\\
& waren die Leute unfreundlich zu mir
    &  1.16 & 0.15 & 0.86 & 1.45 &  3.20& 0.001 & 0.93 & 0.35 \\
& habe ich das Leben genossen [R] 
    & -0.96 & 0.14 & -1.23 & -0.70 & -0.98 & 0.33 &  0.78 & 0.43 \\
& mußte ich weinen 
    & -1.61&  0.17 &  1.29 &  1.94 & -0.09 & 0.93 & -1.75 & 0.08 \\
& war ich traurig 
    &  0.42 & 0.14 &  0.16 &  0.69 & -3.01 & 0.003 & -0.37 & 0.71\\
& hatte ich das Gefühl, daß mich die Leute nicht leiden können 
    &  1.21 & 0.15 & 0.91  &  1.51 & -0.09 & 0.93 &-1.25 & 0.21\\
& konnte ich mich zu nichts aufraffen
    &  0.17 &  0.14 & -0.09 &  0.44 & 0.26 & 0.79  &  1.53 & 0.13
    \\
        \midrule
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\scriptsize $^\ast$  Median als Teilungskriterium;}\\
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\scriptsize $^{\ast\ast}$ Geschlecht als Teilungskriterium}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]